# renaming hard drives (sdc to sdb) on the fly

Tags: hard-drive, rename, hotswap

```
ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
kernel: [2761026.198796] ata2: soft resetting link
kernel: [2761031.226669] ata2.00: disabled
kernel: [2761031.226720] ata2: EH complete
kernel: [2761031.226753] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK,SUGGEST_OK
```

After receiving the error above, I couldn't access /dev/sdb anymore.
Not wanting to restart the server, I rescanned for the device using `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan` and it readded the drive as /dev/sdc.

From what I have found, I need to use `echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 3 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi`, "3" being the SCSI ID which corresponds to sdb.

Everything nice up to the point I execute the command and get `-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`.
  All the solutions point to using this method, but I am unable to. Any other method available?

`Debian 5.0.8 - 2.6.26-1-686`

Comment: Did you run the `echo` command as root? According to [TLDP](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-4.html) your approach looks fine.

Comment: yes, ran it as root.

Comment: @AxelKnauf: If you mean using `sudo`, that won't work. `echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 3 0" | sudo tee /proc/scsi/scsi`

Comment: seemed to be an argument issue. supplying different ones like 1.0.0.0 would not yield an error anymore. but I still couldn't rename the hdd.